# Distribution of Bernoulli and Uniform Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Here's a problem I am stuck on:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables such that $X$ is Bernoulli-distributed with $p=1/2$, and $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. Then:

1. What is the CDF and PDF of $X+Y$ ?
2. Does the PDF of $XY$ exist?
3. What is the CDF of $XY$?

I tried finding the CDF of $X+Y$ by conditioning on $X$ as per [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49291/how-to-compute-the-pdf-of-a-sum-of-a-discrete-and-a-continuous-random-variable), but could not get any further. Can anyone show me what to do, or how to do this?

Comment: "but could not get any further." Please explain why.

Comment: @Did I got $\sum_{x \in {0,1}} P(X+Y=k|X=i)(X=i)$, and rewrote the summand as $P(Y= k-i | X=i)P(X=i)$, which by independence is equal to $P(Y=k-i)P(X=i)$. Expanding the sum, I get $P(Y=k)P(X=0) + P(Y=k-1)P(X=1)$ $= (1/2)P(Y=k) + (1/2)P(Y=k-1) = (1/2)(P(Y=k)+P(Y=k-1))$ and I wasn't sure what to do next.

Comment: The conditioning argument works smoothly. Let $W=X+Y$. We calculate $\Pr(W\le w)$ if $1\lt w\le 2$. We have $W\le w$ if $X=0$ (prob. $1/2$) or $X=1$ and $Y\le w-1$ (prob. $(1/2)(w-1)$). Add. We get $w/2$. Now consider other ranges for $w$.

Comment: Of course P(X+Y=k)=0 for every k.

Comment: For the cdf you also need to deal with $w\lt 0$, $w\ge 2$, and $0\le w\le 1$. Separate treatment is in principle needed for $w=0$ and $w=1$. In the interval $(0,2)$ we get cdf $w/2$. Differentiate to get the density which is $1/2$. You differentiated $w/2$ incorrectly. The number $\frac{1}{2}$ is a constant, so the derivative of $\frac{1}{2}w$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ times the derivative of $w$, that is, $\frac{1}{2}$ times $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The cases $w<0$ and $w \geq 2$ are both impossible, so they have probability $0$. For the case $P(W\leq w)$ with $0 \leq w \leq 1$, we have two cases: if $x=0$ then $P(Y=w) = w$ and if $x=1$ then we want $P(Y=0) = 0$. Adding both gives $P = \frac w 2$. Add $\frac w 2 + \frac w 2 = w$, and divide by two as we had partitioned the interval into two, so we get $w/2$ as the CDF. Differentiating gives a PDF of $\frac 1 2$ on $[0,2]$, which intuitively makes sense when we consider the fact that $Y$ is uniform and $X$, on average, halves the probability. Is that right?

Comment: @AndréNicolas And using a similar technique for $XY$: let $W=XY$. What is $P(W \leq w)$? For $w < 0$ it is impossible, and also for $w > 1$. So we inspect $0 \leq w \leq 1$. With $p=1/2$, we have $X=0$, so $w=0$, so $w \leq W$. If $X=1$, then we need $Y=w$ which has $p=w$. Total probability in this case is $(1/2)w$. Add. Results in CDF $\frac{w+1}{2}$. Differentiate, we get PDF $\frac 1 2$ on the interval $[0,1]$, so $XY$ can't be a density because the integral of that is $1/2$, not $1$. Is that right?

Comment: The cdf is $0$ for $w\lt 0$, and as you pointed out it **jumps** to $1/2$ at $w=0$. For $0\,lt w\le 1$ it is $(w+1)/2$, and it is $1$ for $w\gt 1$.  Note that the cdf is not continuous at $0$. This is not the cdf of a continuous random variable, which is why there is no density function. Our random variable $XY$ is kind of a hybrid of discrete and continuous,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**On 1)**

Let $W:=X+Y$. Then:

$$F_{W}\left(w\right)=P\left(X+Y\leq w\mid X=0\right)P\left(X=0\right)+P\left(X+Y\leq w\mid X=1\right)P\left(X=1\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w\right)+\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w-1\right)$$

Here $F_{Y}$ is well known to you and knowing CDF $F_{W}$ you can
find PDF $f_{W}$.

**On 2)**

$X=0\Rightarrow XY=0$ so that $P\left\{ XY=0\right\} \geq P\left\{ X=0\right\} \geq\frac{1}{2}$.
Draw your conclusions about the existence of a PDF.

**On 3)**

Let $V:=XY$. Then:

$$F_{V}\left(v\right)=P\left(XY\leq v\mid X=0\right)P\left(X=0\right)+P\left(XY\leq v\mid X=1\right)P\left(X=1\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{2}P\left(0\leq v\right)+\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(v\right)$$

Here $P\left(0\leq v\right)=0$ if $v<0$ and $P\left(0\leq v\right)=1$
otherwise.

Comment: Thanks -- I did some work in this vein with the help of Andre Nicolas. Could you please check what I did, as posted in the comments below my question?

Comment: In your comment concerning $X+Y$ you make mistakes. Just apply the formula in my answer to find the correct CDF and discern $4$ cases $w\leq0;0< w\leq1;1<w\leq 2;2<w$. Your result about CDF of $XY$ is correct. Your reasoning for no existence of a PDF is not the most adequate. The reasoning in my answer is better: If $P(V=c)>0$ for some constant $c$ then $V$ has no PDF. Here $V:=XY$.

Comment: If there is a PDF then the CDF must be continuous. $P(V=c)>0$ tells us that this is not the case, so there is no PDF. No that is not the correct CDF you mention. And where is the discernment in $4$ cases?

Comment: Not "wrong" but "narrow" I would say. E.g. there can be a PDF also if the CDF is *not* differentiable. So if possible then avoid it.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help! If you'd like to briefly look over another problem I had, please view it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293927/check-my-work-on-a-poisson-process-distribution-question/1293942#1293942

Comment: By the way, just to make sure -- I'm correct in that the CDF of $X+Y$ is $\frac{2w-1}{2}$, right? This yields a PDF of $1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Again I see only one case, and there are $4$. Make it look like: If $w<0$ then $\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w\right)+\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w-1\right)=0$.
If $0\leq w<1$ then $\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w\right)+\frac{1}{2}F_{Y}\left(w-1\right)=\frac{1}{2}w+0=\frac{1}{2}w$.
If $1\leq w<2$ then ... et cetera.

Comment: Okay, I worked out the four cases. For $w<0$, $F_W(w) = 0$. For $0 \leq w < 1$, it's $w/2$. For $1 \leq w < 2$ it's $(2w-1)/2)$. For $w > 2$, it's $w/2$. Now what do I do? Surely I don't declare the CDF piecewise?

Comment: For $1<w\leq2$ you get $\frac12+\frac12w$ and for $2<w$ you get $1$. Yes declare it piecewise. And also determine the PDF piecewise.

Comment: I note you wrote for $0 \leq w < 1$ and $1 < w \leq 2$. Should I have a separate case for $w=1$?

Comment: No, the CDF is continuous here, so do not bother about that. These are details.

Comment: Ok. Then the pdf is $0$ for $w<0$, $1/2$ for $0 \leq w < 1$, $1/2$ for $1 \leq w < 2$, and $1$ for $w>2$?

Comment: I see that I made a mistake in a former comment. The CDF is $\frac12w+0=\frac12w$ for $0\leq w<1$ and also $\frac12+\frac12(w-1)=\frac12w$ for $1\leq w<2$. Your PDF is okay now. But of course $0\leq w<1$ and $1\leq w<2$ can be taken together.